# Insert folder from Google drive to email

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, gmail-api

I have been trying to insert a folder in my drive to gmail like what it does when we use the action 'Insert files using Drive' and choose a folder.
And the email will insert that folder as an attachment (have an attachment icon), but I can't find any solution. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? If you want to add a folder as an attachment file, unfortunately, it cannot be achieved. If you want to add all files in a folder as the attachment files, it can be achieved. At that time, it is required to be careful the file size.

Comment: @Tanaike It's not really an attachment, it's just a link (with attachment icon and name) that when recipient click at, it navigates to the folder which was already in my drive and they have permission to read. I can do it manually but I have no idea how to do it with Gmail API and Drive API.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about what you want to do? 1. You want to share the specific folder and retrieve the URL of shared folder. 2. You want to send an email with HTML body including the URL as a link. 3. You want to achieve 1 and 2 by Javascript (it's not Google Apps Script.) using Gmail API and Drive API. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, I want to share a folder in my drive and then send an email including  the URL of that folder, but I don't want to present that folder as a plain link but like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s081g.png

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that it can be achieved using Drive API and Gmail API. At first, retrieve the URL for accessing to the shared folder using Drive API. As the next step, send the email with the HTML body including the URL using Gmail API. By the way, can you update your question by including the detail information about what you want to do? I think that it will make users easily see your question. At that time, please add your current script.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, I'll update later, since this is the first time I ask a question here (after search all the internet). As for your answer, It doesn't display as what I want, It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEexX.png But I think It's acceptable for now. Anyway, thanks for your support.